# Why I cannot access the page after adding a migration, even if everything built successfully?

Tags: database, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, localdb

I wanna build a web app that contains a page where I can allocate courses to professors-I already created the login-logout/register pages using Identity API-, in order to do this, I am using Razor Pages Entity Framework (CRUD). I already had some migrations before and I want to add another migration called 'InitialCreate'. I typed the following commands in Packet Manager Console:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate -Context ApplicationDbContext

Update-Database -Context ApplicationDbContext
```

Everything built successfully, but when I run the code and trying to access the page 'AlocareMaterii" which uses the migration through my localhost (localhost:x/AlocareMaterii), I get the following error:

```
A database operation failed while processing the request.
SqlException: Cannot open database "razor_licenta_runtimeContext-a7b890ea-d1ed-4faa-afdf-88dcf8d382d4Trusted_Connection=True" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-3AH99PG\ninex'.
Use migrations to create the database for razor_licenta_runtimeContext
In Visual Studio, use the Package Manager Console to scaffold a new migration and apply it to the database:

PM> Add-Migration [migration name]
PM> Update-Database
Alternatively, you can scaffold a new migration and apply it from a command prompt at your project directory:

> dotnet ef migrations add [migration name]
> dotnet ef database update
```

This is my 'appsettings.json' file:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-razor_licenta_runtime-53bc9b9d-9d6a-45d4-8429-2a2761773502;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "razor_licenta_runtimeContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=razor_licenta_runtimeContext-a7b890ea-d1ed-4faa-afdf-88dcf8d382d4Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, I think your problem is "razor_licenta_runtimeContext" you should use `add-migration initial -context razor_licenta_runtimeContext` for migration and `update-database -context razor_licenta_runtimeContext` I think that it will resolve the issue.

Comment: thanks for your help and sorry for the late reply, it worked now!

Comment: @Cristian happy to help.Happy Coding :)